# blender gltf export looks weird when loaded in three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I exported a simple cube with a material from Blender as a GLTF (GLB) file. When loaded in three.js it doesn't look right, as if I was watching the inside of the cube.

In my example I've put side by side:
- the mesh loaded from the GLTF file (on the left, in the image)
- a mesh with BoxBufferGeometry and a MeshStandardMaterial (on the right, in the image).
I have an ambiente light (HemisphereLight) and a main light (DirectionalLight).
The created mesh looks ok but the loaded mesh looks weird.
When exporting from blender I've tried not exporting the Normals; it got a little better but basically I get the same result. It looks like I'm looking at the cube's interior.

```
let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let mesh;

function init() {
    container = document.querySelector( '#scene-container' );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x8FBCD4 );

    createCamera();
    createLights();
    createMeshes();
    createRenderer();

    renderer.setAnimationLoop( () => {

        render();

  } );
}

function createCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        35, // FOV
        container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, //aspect
        0.1, // near clipping plane
        100, // far clipping plane
    );
    camera.position.set( -1, 1, 10 );
}

function createMeshes() {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x800080 } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    mesh.position.set(2.5, 0, 0);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('models/teste.glb',
                function ( gltf ) {scene.add( gltf.scene );},
                // called while loading is progressing
                function ( xhr ) {console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );},
                function ( error ) {console.log( 'An error happened' );}
                );
}

function createLights() {
    const ambientLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(
    0xddeeff, 
    0x202020, 
    5, 
    );

    const mainLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 5 );
    mainLight.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );

    scene.add( ambientLight, mainLight );
}


function createRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
```

I would expect the left cube (the GLTF one) to look like the right one.

Comment: Does your exported mesh looks okay when you import it in the following `three.js` based `glTF` viewer? https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: No, it does not. What does that mean?

Comment: Can you please share the `glb` in this thread?

Comment: Thank you in advance for your help. Here's the link to the file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gtvge6fsdP3pKjL2qUhuLOpGR14swxra
It's a simple cube (the one that blender creates when you open a new file). I've changed the material to "Principled BSDF" and chose any color. When exporting to GLTF I've let unchanged the parameters with the exception that I only exported the select object. 
What really bugs me is that I did all this in another computer and it worked just fine. Unfortunately I no longer can access that computer to see if there are any differences in the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
I'm on Blender 2.79. I must use the old version of the addon (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter)